# JPG images correctly loads but not showing on SDL

Tags: c++, c, sdl

I have to load and show 20 random images from 6750 jpg images. The images are in jpg format and sometimes shows but not all and not always. this is the part that loads the images using IMG_Load (sorry, my english is bad).

I have image lib correctly installed.
The code is fine because png images works, the problem is only jpg images and i have to use 6570 of them.

```
int i=0,ra;                  
srand(time(NULL));        
char name[18];       
while(i<10){
    ra=rand()%675+1;
    sprintf(name, "icons/icono (%d).jpg",ra);
    strcpy(imgs[i], name);
    imas[i] = IMG_Load(imgs[i]);                               
    printf("icono %s charged\n",imgs[i]);
    i++;}
```

with the printf i can check if the imgs are correctly loaded, i know no errors with the code, is just when i run the program, 2 or 4 images shows and no more.

This is the entire code (ignore comments if you dont speak spanish):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <SDL/SDL.h>
#include <SDL/SDL_image.h>
#include <SDL/SDL_mixer.h>

void limpiar (SDL_Surface *screen);         //Declaración de funciones
void imprimir(SDL_Surface *screen, SDL_Surface *ima, int x, int y);
void mover_objeto(int *x, int *y, int ancho, int alto);


int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    SDL_Surface *screen;                        //la superficie contenedora
    SDL_Surface *ima, *imag, *imas[11];         //la superficie de imagen
    Mix_Music *cancion;                         //el sonido que tenemos
    SDL_Event event;                            //evento a usar en el programa
    int salir = 0;                              //salir esta en falso
    int x = 20;                                 //coordenada x de la imagen
    int y = 100;                                //coordenada y de la imagen

    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO | SDL_INIT_AUDIO) == -1){
       printf("Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError()); return 1;}            //inicialización
    screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(360, 450, 16, SDL_HWSURFACE);         //superficie contenedora
    if (screen == NULL){
       printf("Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError()); return 1;}            //en caso de error de superficie
    SDL_WM_SetCaption("Memorice Warcraft", NULL);                   //titulo de la ventana

//*************  Imagen  ****************
    char imgs[11][18];             
    imag = IMG_Load("icons/00.png"); 
    int i=0,ra;                     //i para carga de imagenes
    srand(time(NULL));           //para no repetir el random
    char name[18];               //en name almacenaremos cada nombre de imagen
    while(i<10){
        ra=rand()%675+1;
        sprintf(name, "icons/icono (%d).jpg",ra);
        strcpy(imgs[i], name);
        imas[i] = IMG_Load(imgs[i]);                                //cargo las imagenes al arreglo
        printf("icono %s cargado\n",imgs[i]);                       //print guardado en stdout.txt
        i++;}


//*************  Audio  ****************
    if (Mix_OpenAudio(44100, MIX_DEFAULT_FORMAT, 2, 4096) == -1){
       printf("Error en Mix_OpenAudio: %s\n", Mix_GetError());     //abrimos un audio de fondo
       return 1;}
    cancion = Mix_LoadMUS("bnet.wav");                             //cargamos la cancion
    if (!cancion)
        printf("Error en Mix_LoadMUS: %s\n", Mix_GetError());      //o tiramos error

    if (cancion){
        if (Mix_PlayMusic(cancion, -1) == -1)                     //corre la pista de musica o error
            printf("Error en Mix_PlayMusic: %s\n", Mix_GetError());}


//**************  While de ejecución  *************
    while (! salir){                             //mientras no hayamos salido del juego
        SDL_PollEvent(&event);                   //esperamos pulsación de tecla
        if (event.type == SDL_QUIT) salir = 1;   //si cerramos la ventama, salimos
        limpiar(screen);                         //llamamos funcion que actualiza
        int j=0;
        int px=20,py=100;
        while(j<20){
            imprimir(screen, imag, px, py);      //pintamos escudos
            px+=64;
            if(j==4 || j==9 || j== 14){py+=64;px=20;}
            j++;}

        Uint8 *key = SDL_GetKeyState(NULL);
        if (key[SDLK_4])                             //al presionar tecla
           imprimir(screen, imas[0], 20, 100);       //mostramos imagen respectiva
        if (key[SDLK_5])    
           imprimir(screen, imas[1], 84, 100);
        if (key[SDLK_6])    
           imprimir(screen, imas[2], 148, 100);
        if (key[SDLK_7])    
           imprimir(screen, imas[6], 212, 100);
        if (key[SDLK_8])    
           imprimir(screen, imas[7], 276, 100);
        if (key[SDLK_e])    
           imprimir(screen, imas[8], 20, 164);
        if (key[SDLK_r])    
           imprimir(screen, imas[3], 84, 164);
        if (key[SDLK_t])    
           imprimir(screen, imas[0], 148, 164);
        if (key[SDLK_y])    
           imprimir(screen, imas[2], 212, 164);
        if (key[SDLK_u])    
           imprimir(screen, imas[9], 276, 164);
        if (key[SDLK_s])    
           imprimir(screen, imas[1], 20, 228);
        if (key[SDLK_d])    
           imprimir(screen, imas[4], 84, 228);
        if (key[SDLK_f])    
           imprimir(screen, imas[6], 148, 228);
        if (key[SDLK_g])    
           imprimir(screen, imas[7], 212, 228);
        if (key[SDLK_h])    
           imprimir(screen, imas[8], 276, 228);
        if (key[SDLK_z])    
           imprimir(screen, imas[9], 20, 292);
        if (key[SDLK_x])    
           imprimir(screen, imas[5], 84, 292);
        if (key[SDLK_c])    
           imprimir(screen, imas[3], 148, 292);
        if (key[SDLK_v])    
           imprimir(screen, imas[4], 212, 292);
        if (key[SDLK_b])    
           imprimir(screen, imas[5], 276, 292);

        SDL_Flip(screen);                        //mostramos la superficie contenedora
        SDL_Delay(10);                           //delay de actualización
        }

    if (cancion){
       Mix_HaltMusic();                         //forma correcta de terminar el audio
       Mix_FreeMusic(cancion);}
    Mix_CloseAudio();

    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}


void limpiar (SDL_Surface *screen){                             //funcion que actualiza
    Uint32 a = SDL_MapRGB(screen->format, 50, 100, 155);        //fondo azulado
    SDL_FillRect(screen, NULL, a);                              //ponemos el fondo
}

//pinta la imagen en la surface, recibiendo la imagen,  x  e  y
void imprimir(SDL_Surface *screen, SDL_Surface *ima, int x, int y){
    SDL_Rect rect = {x, y, 0, 0};                           //crea un nuevo rectángulo
    SDL_BlitSurface(ima, NULL, screen, &rect);              //para pintar la imagen
}

void mostrar_imagen(SDL_Surface *screen, SDL_Surface *imas){
    Uint8 *boton = SDL_GetKeyState(NULL);
    if (boton[SDLK_e])
        printf("ok adasdsad %d",1);
    }
```

I know the solution is use png images, but i dont know how to convert 6750 of them in less than 1 week.

If any of you know the solution or how to convert that 6750 jpg images to png in minits or less, i'll be very greatful.

Comment: But you *don't* check if the image loaded successfully, all you are doing is printing the file-name, not the status of the `IMG_Load` function. You need to check if [`IMG_Load`](https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_image/docs/SDL_image_11.html) returns `NULL` or not.

Comment: i think that's not the problem, i already check that with something like

if (ima == NULL)
        {
                printf("Error in IMG_Load= %s\n", SDL_GetError());
                return 1;
        }

Comment: I see no such checks in the code you show. Please try  to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us. We don't need to see the random file stuff, or the audio code, or the event handler, but we do need to see some actual code including error checks.